# Maven module Dependency

Tags: maven

I have 2 maven modules 1 and 2 and I wanted to call a class defined in module1 from module2 but this class itself depends on some other modules which are added as dependency to its pom.xml.So what is the best way to add module1 to module2 so that it can detect all the dependencies of module1 automatically.And one more thing does maven look into the class path? Or everything has to be added as a dependency.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just add module1 as a dependency to module2. Dependency management in Maven is transitive: if project A depends on project B and project B depends on project C then project A depends on project C.

Maven doesn't take the classpath into account: all dependencies should be expressed directly or indirectly in your projects' POM's.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I have another issue..i am running the main class using mvn exec:java(No issues with this) in module2.Now i am loading a class present in module1 using reflections.When i do the same thing using java,i add the module to the build path.So using maven what should i do???

Comment: I believe you need to do nothing.  Most plugin is aware of the dependency.  If in mod2, you have mod1 as dependency, mvn exec:java in mod2 should already have mod1 in classpath.

Comment: Okay..Taking that as true I am trying to load the class in module1 using reflection using module2.Now in this case it shows an error in one of the imports present in module1(ClassnotFoundException).I have tried adding that jar everywhere but the error prevails.

Comment: Are you still using mvn exec to run your program? Have you tried putting all of your dependencies in a directory and run your program from there, after setting your classpath accordingly?

Comment: Yes i am using mvn exec to run the program.Since the no of dependencies are huge,i dont want to run the code in that way and i dont know how many dependencies are there...So i would prefer this way if possible.

Comment: Do all dependencioes have compile scope (i.e. the default one)?